# How to connect two Vlans to Database server

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

[image: Vlan]

How to connect two Vlans to communicate with the Database server
I have a Cisco SG200-50 50-port Gigabit Smart Switch
    The sg200-50 Smart switch is layer two.
  First vlan ip address range 50.50.50.2
Second vlan ip address range 192.168.100.1

Comment: You have specified IP address while you've mentioned **range**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to cross from one subnet (layer 3 boundary) to another, you need a router.  The SG200 is a layer 2 only switch.

You might also consider putting all your devices into one VLAN, although with the limited information you've provided, I can't recommend that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If the server has two NIC card, you can connect one NIC to vlan related to 50.50.50.2 subnet and second NIC to vlan 192.168.100.1. I have seen the environment where server can support trunk with one NIC card, and from the switch side, enable trunk and allowed vlan list, not sure for your server it support or not. Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: my server doesn't support it.

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 mandatory steps:

1) Create the vlans

```
Vlan 10
Vlan 20
```

2) Create vlan interfaces

```
int vlan 10
ip add 50.50.50.1/24 
int vlan 20 
192.168.100.1/24
```

3) Assign relevant interfaces to correct vlan. E.g. lets imagine fa0/1 is pointing to PC0 ( vlan 1).

```
int fa0/1 
switchport mode access 
switchport access vlan 10
```

4) Enable `ip routing` on the switch.

**NOTE:** Do not forget to put a default GW on the PCs pointing to the address of the switch in the respective vlan.

E.g. If PC0 is in vlan 10 following setting will be fine:

```
IP 192.168.100.10 
SM 255.255.255.0
GW 192.168.10.1 ( IP of the SW in VLAN 10)
```

Comment: SG200 is a layer 2 only switch